# How do I find the distance through two parallel lines with the equations of $y=-3x+4$ and $y=-3x+1$?

Tags: geometry

So my teacher likes to give us stuff she never taught us as homework and as I was working I got a problem that says, “Find the distance between the parallel lines. If necessary, round your answer to the nearest tenth.” There is a graph showing two parallel lines with the equations of $y=-3x+4$ and $y=-3x+1$ and I have no idea how to do this, I can’t find a formula for it anywhere either. Heres a picture of the problem:

[image]

Comment: Is there anything you've been taught that seems like it could be related? e.g. finding the distance between other geometric objects?

Comment: We have learned how to find the distance between points  using distance formula, d=√((x_2-x_1)²+(y_2-y_1)²) but that's it.

Comment: Do you know a way to find an equation of a line perpendicular to one of these lines?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean the shortest distance between the two lines. Find the slope that is perpendicular to the lines. This slope is $\frac{1}{3}$. The y-intercept of this new line should not matter, so we can say that the shortest distance between the lines is some segment of $y=\frac{x}{3}$. We solve the following system for $x$ and $y$:

$$\begin{cases}y=\frac{x}{3}\\\\ y=-3x+4\end{cases}$$

To obtain $x=\frac{6}{5}$ and $y=\frac{2}{5}$. Similarly, solve this system

$$\begin{cases}y=\frac{x}{3}\\\\ y=-3x+1\end{cases}$$

To obtain $x=\frac{3}{10}, y=\frac{1}{10}$. The distance between these two points is:

$$\sqrt{\left(\frac{3}{10}-\frac{6}{5}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{10}-\frac{2}{5}\right)^2}=\frac{3\sqrt{10}}{10}$$

Answer (score 2):

There is a formula for the distance between a point $P = (x_1, y_1) $ and the line

$$ a x+ b y + c = 0 $$

This distance is given by

$$ d = \dfrac{ | a x_1 + b y_1 + c | }{ \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} } $$

Therefore, to find the distance between the two given lines, pick a point on the first line which is given by $y = -3 x + 4$.  For example, choose $x = 0$, then $y = 4$.  Now find the distance between this point $(0, 4)$ and the second line whose equation is $ y = -3 x + 1 $, which when put in standard form becomes $3 x + y -1 = 0 $.  The distance according to the above formula is

$$ d = \dfrac{ | 3(0) + (4) - 1 | }{\sqrt{ 3^2 + 1^2}} = \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{10}} $$

Answer (score 0):

To make things simpler it is convenient to move one of the lines, so that it passes through the coordinate origin where x=0 and y=0. This is easily done by removing the constant so that
$y = -3x +1 \ \ \ \  (eq1)$ becomes $y = -3x \ \ \ \ (eq2)$

To keep the separation the same, the second parallel line has to be moved vertically by the same amount, so we subtract 1 from that too, so that $y = -3x +4 \ \ \ \ (eq3)$ becomes $y = -3x + 3 \ \ \ \ (eq4)$

Now we want to find the separation distance that is perpendicular to the two lines. We can rotate a line by 90 degrees, around  the origin, by changing the sign of y term and then swapping the x and y terms, so when we rotate eq2, the equation of the perpendicular line is $y = x/3 \ \ \ \ (eq5)$

Now we have to find the intersection of our new perpendicular line with the second vertical parallel line on the right. We do this by equating eq5 with eq4 so that $x/3 = -3x +3 \ \ \ \  (eq6)$. Solving for x: $x= 9/10  \ \ \ \ (eq7)$

This is the x coordinate of the intersection. The y coordinate is obtained by inserting this value for x in eq5 so that $y = x/3 =(9/10)/3 = 3/10  \ \ \ \ (eq8)$

Now we have x,y coordinates for the intersection of two lines and we have conveniently arranged for the other intersection to be at (0,0) we can use Pythagoras theorem to determine the perpendicular separation of two points $(\Delta s)$:

$\Delta s =  \sqrt{(\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2}  =  \sqrt{(eq7)^2 + (eq8)^2}\ \ \ \ (eq9)$

$\Delta s =  \sqrt{(9/10)^2 + (3/10)^2} = \sqrt{\frac 9{10}} = \frac 3 {\sqrt{10}} \approx 0.9$

Answer (score 0):

From the $y$-intercept of $y= -3x+1$, a perpendicular is drawn which meets $y= -3x+4$ at $ R$.

The slope of the given line $\tan\phi = \tan (\theta + \frac{π}{2} ) = -3$

Here $\angle QST = \theta$

We get $\tan \theta = \frac{1}{3}$

By corresponding angles and alternative interior angle theorem, we get $\angle QPR = \theta$.

$PQR$ is a right triangle at $R$ and $QP = 3$. So $QR$ is $QP \cdot \sin\theta$.

$QP = 3 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} = \frac {3}{\sqrt{10}}$

There is also a formula for this

Distance = $\frac {|c_1 - c_2|}{\sqrt {1+m^2}}$
[image]